# My SwiftUI FetchRequest display no items although there is 10 items

Tags: xcode, swiftui, core-data, watchos, nsfetchrequest

This is what I have in code:

```
struct ServicesView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name, ascending: false)], animation: .easeIn) var results: FetchedResults<Category>

    var body: some View {
        List(results) { category in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                Text(category.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("x\(category.services.count)")
            })
        }
        .overlay(
            Text(results.isEmpty ? "Nothing here" : "")
        )
        .onAppear {
            print("")
            print(Category.numberOfEntities())
        }
    }
}
```

On console is displayed:

> 10

Why there is nothing on the list?

[image]

How number is calculated?

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    static func defaultContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        CoreDataManager.shared.defaultContext!
    }
}


protocol Fetchable {
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    static func numberOfEntities() -> Int
}

extension Fetchable where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static var entityName: String {
        entity().name ?? ""
    }
    static func numberOfEntities() -> Int {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.defaultContext()
        do {
            return try context.count(for: request)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("❌ Core Data Count Error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose the issue is here, because I don't assign `@Environment’s managedObjectContext` anywhere. How should I do it?

```
@main
struct Watch_AppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                TabView {
                    TimerView()
                    ContentView()
                    ServicesView()  // how do I assign here managed object context?
                    Text("4th page")
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .onAppear(perform: loadData) //load data, fetch categories from cloudkit and save to core data, is is fetched and saved
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to `print(Category.numberOfEntities())` could you `print(results.count)`
 or just `print(results)`, since this is what you display. Show the code for `Category.numberOfEntities()`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine `results.count` is `0`. I have updated the question.

Comment: well what do you know, `results.count` is zero. You know now why no items are displayed.

Comment: Ok, but why it is zero? It should not. There is in core data 10 Categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add the `ManagedObjectContext` to your view from which you are trying to fetch the data from.

You can add it like this to your view:

```
struct ServicesView: View {
    // The context for your view
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

   @FetchRequest(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name, ascending: false)], animation: .easeIn) var results: FetchedResults<Category>

    var body: some View {
        List(results) { category in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                Text(category.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("x\(category.services.count)")
            })
        }
        .overlay(
            Text(results.isEmpty ? "Nothing here" : "")
        )
        .onAppear {
           print("")
           print(Category.numberOfEntities())
        }
    }
}
```

To pass the context from your entry view you have to get the context from your `PersistenceController`, like so:

```
@main
struct Watch_AppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                TimerView()
                ContentView()
                ServicesView()  
                    // Assign the context
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.context)
                Text("4th page")
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .onAppear(perform: loadData) //load data, fetch categories from cloudkit and save to core data, is is fetched and saved
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation of Core Data here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata